# Convert SQL Server query to Entity Framework query

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I have a SQL Server query like this:

```
select 
    month(fact_date) as month,
    sum(case when beef_dairy_stat = 1 and param_id = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as cnt
from 
    user_behave_fact
where 
    YEAR(fact_date) = 2018
group by 
    month(fact_date)
order by 
    month
```

with a result of

```
month   cnt
------------
  1     10
  2     20
```

Now I need to convert this query to its corresponding Entity Framework query.

This is my current attempt:

```
var sql_rez_ICC = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();

sql_rez_ICC = db.user_behave_fact
                    .Where(x => x.fact_date.Value.Year == selected_year)
                    .GroupBy(y => y.fact_date.Value.Month)
                    .Select(y =>new { month = y.Select(x=>x.fact_date.Value.Month), icc_count = y.Count(x => x.beef_dairy_stat == true && x.param_id == 1) })
                    .AsEnumerable()
                    .Select(y => new Tuple<int, int>(y.month, y.icc_count))
                    .ToList();
```

However on second `.Select`, I get an error on month which is

> Cannot convert from System.Collection.Generic.IEnumrable to int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`y.Select(x=>x.fact_date.Value.Month)` returns an `IEnumerable<int>`. Use `y.Key` instead.